# How can i apply Masonry, or Grid Layout to my blogger template

Tags: html, css, grid, blogger, masonry

i recently created my own website from the help of a free custom template (it's now 80% customized to my own preference), i am using blogger platform for my website.

I am planning to apply a Masonry/Grid layout to my website. I have googled for few days but to no avail.

this is the link i am following, it does work, however it is messed up, i think it could be something about the width or whatnot because it doesnt really appear to be inside my main page container. [masonry blogger tutorial](http://www.bloggerever.com/2013/08/tips-of-using-of-masonry-plugin-on.html)

[here is my website link](http://www.andeansam.com/)

I need guidance on every step i need to do in order to make this work for my website as i am not very advance in html, but i am a fast learner, i will be using the grid layout on a [specific page](http://www.andeansam.com/search/label/Editorial) on my website.